# Proving that $\|T\|=\max\{\sqrt{\lambda};\;\lambda\in \sigma(T^*T)\}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on an **infinite-dimensional**  complex Hilbert space $F$.

It is well known that if  $T\in \mathcal{B}(F)$, then
$$\|T\|=\displaystyle\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|.$$

> I want to prove that for $T\in \mathcal{B}(F)$, we have
>   $$\|T\|=\max\{\sqrt{\lambda};\;\lambda\in \sigma(T^*T)=\sigma(TT^*)\},$$
>   where $\sigma(A)$ denotes the spectrum of an operator $A$.

Comment: The operators $T^\ast T$ and $TT^\ast$ do not always have the same spectrum, but $\sigma(T^\ast T)\setminus\{0\}=\sigma(T T^\ast)\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @MaoWao Thank you. So the formula is only true for $\sigma(T^*T)$?

Comment: No, it works either way. The maxima of $\sigma(T^\ast T)$ and $\sigma(T T^\ast)$ do coincide, as the formula $\sigma(T^\ast T)\setminus\{0\}=\sigma(TT^\ast)\setminus\{0\}$ shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. for each $A \in \mathcal{B}(F)$ we have $||A^*A||=||A||^2$.
2. if $A \in \mathcal{B}(F)$ is self-adjoint, then $||A|| =\max \{| \mu|: \mu \in \sigma(A)\}$.
3. if $T \in \mathcal{B}(F)$, then $T^*T$ is self-adjoint and $ \sigma(T^*T) \subseteq [0, \infty)$.

Now you should be in a position to prove $\|T\|=\max\{\sqrt{\lambda};\;\lambda\in \sigma(T^*T)\}$.